# Angularjs not rendering when passed from MVC view to a div

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have a MVC controller which returns a partial view by the name "userdetails.cshtml". Its returning the following code

```
@{
var d = (Dictionary<string, string>)ViewData["userdetails_dic"];
Layout = Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}



<div ng-app="usermodule">
<div ng-controller="usercontroller" data-ng-init="init(@Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d))">
    <div style="text-align:center;background-color: #dfdf00 ;font-size:18px;"><b>USER DETAILS</b></div>
    <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in dict">
        <p>{{key}} : {{value}}</p>
        <p>dict["uid"]</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('usermodule', ['ngSanitize']);

myApp.controller('usercontroller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.init = function (dic) {
        $scope.dict = dic;
    }
});
```

now i have a "mainpage.cshtml"in which i am calling a controller action through ajax call, and controller in return returns the view in "userdetails.cshtml".

```
<script>

var app = angular.module("myapp", ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller('myctrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$sce', function ($scope, $http, $sce) {

    $scope.gobutton = function () {

        $http.get('/profile/userdetails/' + $scope.uidng).success(
            function (response) {
                $scope.userdetails = $sce.trustAsHtml(response);
                alert($scope.userdetails)
            },
            function (failure)
            { console.log("failed :(", failure); });


    }
}
]);
```

problem is angularjs in "userdetails.cshtml" is not rendering when i am calling it in "mainpage.cshtml" through ajax call. i am getting output as

{{key}} : : {{value}}

rather than real values. 
When i am calling controller action in particular on browser by typing full route(/.../.../userdetails) angularjs is rendering.
On console following error is displayed - https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$digest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use AngularJs in jQuery manners... In Angular world, you normally don't manipulate DOMs directly. What you should do is:

1. put the following html in your main.cshtml page.

`<div style="text-align:center;background-color: #dfdf00 ;font-size:18px;"><b>USER DETAILS</b></div>
    <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in dict">
        <p>{{key}} : {{value}}</p>
        <p>dict["uid"]</p>
    </div>`

You probably want to use `ng-show or ng-hide` to control the display of this section. One simple way to do is to check whether dict object has data.

2. Modify your `profile/userdetails` method in your controller to only return dict data in JSON format.
3. Change your gobutton function to something like below:

   $scope.gobutton = function () {

   ```
   $http.get('/profile/userdetails/' + $scope.uidng).success(
       function (response) {
           // this will automatically update your ng-repeat section
           $scope.dict = response;
       },
       function (failure)
       { console.log("failed :(", failure); });
   ```

   }

Comment: okay will try this method. Original problem is i am trying to process 2 angular js script parallel...following error is displayed in console. Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
[link]http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest